# How to save wikitext result of WikipediR query in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, wikipedia

I am using WikipediR package in R to query Wikipedia, and the code is like this:

```
sink("output.txt",type = "output")
page_content("en","wikipedia", page_name = "Philipp Melanchthon",  
as_wikitext=TRUE)
```

Everything goes fine, but I don't know how to **only** save the markup **wikitext** result in a file. Is there any way instead of using `sink` to save the result properly?

Comment: The return value of `page_content()` is a list classed as `'pcontent'`. From my investigation, this list contains one component named `parse` which is an unclassed list containing three components: a character `title`, an integer `revid`, and another list named `wikitext`, which contains one component weirdly named `*` which is a one-element character string containing the markup source of the page. It doesn't make sense to try to save such a structure as tabular data (xlsx or csv). Look into `save()`, `save.image()`, and `saveRDS()` to save the R object in an R-specific binary format.

Comment: Ah, but perhaps you want to save the markup source as a text file. See my answer for how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the markup source of the Wikipedia page as a text file you can do this:

```
library('WikipediR');
x <- page_content('en','wikipedia',page_name='Philipp Melanchthon',as_wikitext=T);
writeLines(x$parse$wikitext$`*`,'output.txt');
```

Comment: Thx, that is really what I want, sorry for the ambiguous question.